# Multer gives req.file undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, multer

I am trying to upload a file using `multer`. Here's the code:

HTML

```
<form action="/" method="post" encrypt="multipart/form-data" >
      <input  name="upl"  type="file" ></br>
      <input  type="text" name="onenee" ></br>
      <input type="submit" value="submit" />

</form>
```

NODE JS

```
var express = require('express');
// var csrf = require('csurf');
var passport = require('passport');
var Product = require('../models/product');
var multer  = require('multer');
var upload = multer({ dest: 'public/uploads/' });

var router = express.Router();

router.post('/', upload.single('upl'), function (req, res, next) {
        console.log(' Field name1 '+ req.body.onenee);
        console.log(' Field name2 '+ req.files);
        console.log(' Field name3 '+ req.file);
        res.send(req.file);
});
```

OUTPUT I GET FROM THE CONSOLE

> Field name1 hi
>
> Field name2 undefined
>
> Field name3 undefined
>
> POST / 200 15.536 ms - -

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your form attribute is incorrect, change `encrypt` to `enctype` instead.
Your file will be available through `req.file`

UPDATE:
Rename your file with extension:

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination: function(req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, './public/uploads/'); // Make sure this folder exists
        },
        filename: function(req, file, cb) {
            var ext = file.originalname.split('.').pop();
            cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + '.' + ext);
        }
    }),
    upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single('upl');

router.post('/', upload, function (req, res, next) {
        console.log('body', req.body);
        console.log('file', req.file);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for that. I want to kill myself now.

Comment: But, the file extention is missing. How can i get that ? :S

Comment: It's because multer creates a filename for you to make them unique, i don't know why they doesn't add the extension. I'll update the example with code to rename the file with extension.

Comment: @Illep Try this code, i'm using it myself and it's working.

Comment: Thanks but, its not working. I am using ` multer-s3`. Maybe because of that

Answer (score 0):

Do not use:

`cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + '.' + ext);`

Instead of use this below code

```
cb(null, Date.now() + '.jpg');
```